# prettier does not underline warnings of .ts file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Using Visual Source code, I have installed prettier. I have also installed prettier plugin for vscode.
I would like to know how to display the underline for errors. I can see them with eslint enabled but not with prettier alone. Maybe only eslint plugin allow that visual fonctionnality.
However the formatting works. It is just a visual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Prettier is even supposed to highlight formatting errors. It's simply meant to fix them, perhaps automatically when you save the file. ESLint highlights errors because many of its rules are not auto-fixable.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have already mentioned, prettier doesn't inherently underline problems. However, if you want a good plug in that underlines and offers autofix for prettier and linting problems, try this:

https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier